# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.servlet.Controller

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, crud

I am trying out the example given for [CRUD operations in JSP](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-jsp-and-servlet-using-jtable-jquery-plug-in/). But getting error in calling controller.

When I execute the code as given by them I'm getting following error:

```
May 08, 2015 12:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 08, 2015 12:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
May 08, 2015 12:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [147] milliseconds.
May 08, 2015 12:01:20 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\coding\eclipse32Juno\workspace\web\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\jTableServletSetup\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 08, 2015 12:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\coding\eclipse32Juno\workspace\web\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\AjaxCurdjTableServlet\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
May 08, 2015 12:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 08, 2015 12:01:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
May 08, 2015 12:01:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1305 ms
May 08, 2015 12:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Controller as unavailable
May 08, 2015 12:01:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Controller
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.servlet.Controller
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Then I changed `index.jsp` as below to check if Controller is getting called:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CRUD operations using jTable in J2EE</title>
<!-- Include one of jTable styles. -->
<link href="css/metro/blue/jtable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<!-- Include jTable script file. -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
            title : 'Students List',
            actions : {
                listAction : 'Controller?action=list',
                createAction : 'Controller?action=create',
                updateAction : 'Controller?action=update',
                deleteAction : 'Controller?action=delete'
            },
            fields : {
                studentId : {
                    title : 'Student Id',
                    width : '30%',
                    key : true,
                    list : true,
                    edit : false,
                    create : true
                },
                name : {
                    title : 'Name',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                department : {
                    title : 'Department',
                    width : '30%',
                    edit : true
                },
                emailId : {
                    title : 'Email',
                    width : '20%',
                    edit : true
                }
            }
        });
        //$('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 80%; margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; text-align: center;">
        <h4>AJAX based CRUD operations using jTable in J2ee</h4>
        <div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <form action="Controller" method="get">
    Form contents:
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I click on button it results into following error:

```
May 08, 2015 12:07:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Controller as unavailable
May 08, 2015 12:07:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Controller
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.servlet.Controller
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm unable to get where I am doing wrong.

Here is my project directory structure:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415133/where-do-we-put-the-servlets-in-the-directory-structure-of-tomcat

Comment: Please, look into resulted WAR file and check file Controller.class exists in directory WEB-INF/classes/com/servlet/

Comment: I think the problem might be with jar files added.. may be I have added some conflicting jars. but i'm not sure..

Comment: `Controller.class` is there at other location `AjaxCurdjTableServlet\build\classes\com\servlet`

Comment: this is build folder, you need to unpack WAR file (rename it to zip and eztract in some directory). Also check Controller.java has package name equals to `com.servlet`. Also remove servlet-api,jar from lib directory.

Comment: I don't have it's war file, `Controller.java` has package name `com.servlet` and I tried by removing `servlet-api.jar` too. but no effect.

Comment: just to mention about jar files... I have added all jar files from their .zip source code into their mentioned folders.. and also I added all jar files from paths: `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\lib`, `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\lib`

Comment: Please post your `web.xml`

Comment: It is same as given at http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/jquery-jtable-in-servlets-and-jsp/

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your project set up ( at work the proxy strips out the diagrams ) but I am guessing you have servlet-api.jar in your web-inf/lib directory.

If you have, remove it and clean and rebuild your project. The servlet container is also providing an instance of this jar and I think the two are conflicting.

Comment: did you stop the application server, clean the project and rebuild it? does the log file still contain the error `See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class` ?

Comment: Yes, I did.. stopped server, cleaned project and then executed again. but still problem persists..